# Проблема с версткой. Как исправить?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Столкнулся с такой проблемой верстки - на странице [www.alkonarkostop.com.ua/index.php/vazhno-znat](http://www.alkonarkostop.com.ua/index.php/vazhno-znat) меню уехало под тексты статей, а должно быть справа от статей, на одном уровне. Помогите, пожалуйста, исправить этот недочет, если разбираетесь в верстке. Заранее спасибо.

Дело в том, что раньше все отображалось нормально... а потом съехало.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас в html жестко прописано 100% еще и '!important':

[image]

*Чтобы убрать горизонтальный скролл, уберите див, который обведен красным, или уберите из этого дива класс "menutop"*:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Вы не тому контейнеру задаете ширину - вы главному задали 70%
.contentwidthr (этому контейнеру необходимо 100%), а этому задать

```
#vt_main_com .vt_component_inside { 
float: left; padding: 0px; width: 70%;
}
```

Comment: @soledar10, Ваше решение работает, однако отображается кривовато, не так, как на других страницах сайта.